# Finding the middle index between any two indexes in a circular array

Tags: javascript, arrays, modulo

I have an array and three indexes:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var f = 0; // first element
var l = arr.length - 1; // last element
var c = 0; // current element
```

I'm trying to write a function that makes the index `c` to cycle through the array. The requirement is for it to never reach the index `l`. So, whenever `c` reaches a certain value, `f` and `l` need to be increased as well.

A reasonable value to work as a limit for c I thought would be the middle point between f and l. The function I wrote is this:

```
var mod = function(x, m) {
    var r = x%m;
    return r<0 ? r+m : r;
}

while (true) {
    console.log('f', f, 'l', l, 'c', c);
    if (c == l) {
       console.log('error');
    }

    c = mod(c + 1, arr.length);

   if (c > mod(l - f, arr.length) / 2) {
      f = mod(f + 1, arr.length);
      l = mod(l + 1, arr.length);
   }
}
```

It doesn't work, clearly. Is there a nice simple formula to with the modulo operator to get what I want or the approach is totally wrong?

Here's a fiddle to try it: https://jsfiddle.net/wku37h9e/2/

Edit:
Explaining the purpose of this would be a bit long. Let's just say that in the array are stored the positions of external elements which I have to constantly move around. When the `c` is close to the `l`, I advance all the indexes. Graphically would be like this:

```
1. [f|c] [   ] [   ] [ l ]
2. [ f ] [ c ] [   ] [ l ]
3. [ l ] [ f ] [ c ] [   ] // here I start moving things around
4. [   ] [ l ] [ f ] [ c ]
5. [ c ] [   ] [ l ] [ f ]
6. [ f ] [ c ] [   ] [ l ]
```

And so on. With more elements in the array there would be more distance between the indexes.

I also use a different than normal version of mod to take in account negative numbers.

I hope it's a bit clearer now

Comment: why would you do that? please add an example.

Comment: I added a visual explanation

Comment: the start position 1 and position 5 leads to different result. should the position of `c` move `f` and `l`?

Comment: That is how it's supposed to work. When `c` gets too close to `l`, `l` moves forward, so does `f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A reasonable value to work as a limit for `c` I thought would be the middle point between `f` and `l`

Finding the mean average between two values, `low` and `high`, in mod `len`

```
function midPoint(low, high, len) {
    var mid;
    low %= len;
    high %= len;
    while (low < 0) low += len; // these two lines are the
    while (high < low) high += len; // most important for direction
    mid = (low + high) / 2; // mean average
    mid %= len; // convert back to our mod
    return mid;
}
```

So have

```
// works as expected beyond range of mod
midPoint( 1, -1, 9); // middle of 1..8 (mod 9) = 4.5
midPoint(-7,  5, 9); // middle of 2..5 (mod 9) = 3.5
midPoint(-6, 12, 9); // middle of 3..3 (mod 9) = 3
// and
midPoint( 2,  5, 9); // middle of 2..5 (mod 9) = 3.5
midPoint( 5,  2, 9); // middle of 5..2 (mod 9) = 8 (we went the other way around)
```

---

You don't actually have to force the mod until after the whole calculation, so if you really wanted you could do the following, but you **lose direction around the loop**

```
function midPoint(A, B, len) {
    var mid;
    mid = (A + B) / 2; // mean average
    mid %= len; // convert back to our mod
    while (mid < 0) mid += len; // always positive
    return mid;
}
```

Notice here, however

```
midPoint(-6, 3, 9); // middle of 3..3 (mod 9) = 7.5
midPoint( 3, 3 + 0 * 9, 9); // middle of 3..3 (mod 9) = 3
midPoint( 3, 3 + 1 * 9, 9); // middle of 3..3 (mod 9) = 7.5
midPoint( 3, 3 + 2 * 9, 9); // middle of 3..3 (mod 9) = 3
```

i.e. the mid point of `3..3` (mod 9) is both `3` and `7.5`, which is **true**, but which way around we've gone now depends on `k` (where `B - A = k * len + a`)

Comment: This seems like what I needed but still is not working. I always start from this:
`f = 0, l=3, c=0 and len=4`. So it goes like this:

`c=0  | f=0, l=3, m=1.5`;
`c=1  | f=0, l=3, m=1.5`;
`c=2 | f=1, l=0, m=2.5`;
`c=3 | f=2, l=1, m=3.5`;
At this point the m is stuck at 3.5, and after some iterations c will reach l. I'm thinking that maybe I have to round the m down

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand - when I define the mod function that all works:

```
function test() {
    var i=0;
    var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    var f = 0; // first element
    var l = arr.length - 1; // last element
    var c = 0; // current element
    while (true && i < 1000) {
        ++i;
        console.log('f', f, 'l', l, 'c', c);
        if (c == l) {
           console.log('error');
           break;
        }

        c = mod(c + 1, arr.length);

        if (c > mod(l - f, arr.length) / 2) {
           f = mod(f + 1, arr.length);
           l = mod(l + 1, arr.length);
        }
    }
}
function mod(a,b) { return a % b;}
```

Seems to loop c through the possible values, and `c` is never the same as the (continuously recalculated) value of `l`... but I don't understand the arithmetic you're trying to apply to `f` and `l` there

Comment: I edited the question adding some visual explanation and the mod function definition. It's true that your version is working, but I originally used a different mod function to take into account negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I calculate only `l` with the half of the array length plus `c`. `f` is then the next index. All numbers are positve.

> ```
>                             c   f   l
> 1. [ c ] [   ] [ l ] [ f ]  0   3   2  l = length / 2 + c, f = l + 1  both mod length
> 2. [ f ] [ c ] [   ] [ l ]  1   0   3
> 3. [ l ] [ f ] [ c ] [   ]  2   1   0
> 4. [   ] [ l ] [ f ] [ c ]  3   2   1
> 5. [ c ] [   ] [ l ] [ f ]  0   3   2
> 6. [ f ] [ c ] [   ] [ l ]  1   0   3
> ```

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        c, f, l;

for (c = 0; c < arr.length; c++) {
    l = (arr.length / 2 + c) % arr.length;
    f = (l + 1) % arr.length;
    document.write('c:' + c + ' f: ' + f + ' l: ' + l + '<br>');
}
```